# I want to disable CTRL+ALT+DEL in Windows XP in my ANSI-C code?

Tags: c, windows

I want to disable CTRL+ALT+DEL in Windows XP in my ANSI-C code. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: No it isn't. Why would you want to do it anyway?

Comment: You should clarify what exactly you mean by disable and why you want to do this.

Comment: i have an application the user requirement is to disable all inputs when the application is running the only way to stop is to restart system. i have disabled all keys by using  Blockinput(true) but it allows alt+ctrl+del how can i disable this.

Comment: You can edit the registry to disallow task manager. I have edited my post with links to things you might find useful.

Comment: When you administer a public computer, you definitely wish you could do this. And a more specific subset: student computers, especially during class and while running a exam program.

Comment: is it a good way to do this just replace the task manager exe with same name but any other exe file i do it for me it works.......

Comment: @moon: Do you want to prevent use of the task manager, or disable control alt delete? Those are **very** different things.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, Trapping Ctrl-Alt-Del (Secure Attention Sequence) and disabling it are two different things. Despite misconceptions of many it is possible to disable SAS.

Here are 3 ways to do it:

1. Set HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System/DisableTaskMgr = 1
2. Replace msgina.dll with your own or write a keyboard driver.
3. Go to the Start menu, select Run, and type "gpedit.msc" to run the Group Policy editor. Look in User Configuration | Administrative Templates | System and you'll find a section called Ctrl+Alt+Del Options - "Remove Task Manager"

In order to trap SAS, you could write a GINA stub, create a keyboard driver or replace TaskMgr.exe

These requirements arise mainly for embedded systems and you have control over how the WinXP image is made.

Reference: [MSDN Mag Sept 2002](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188951.aspx)

Comment: Finally someone else who isn't saying this is impossible!

Comment: Ya, it's definitely possible. +1 for quoting MSDN.

Comment: You haven't disabled Control-Alt-Delete, you've only disabled the task manager. You can still do things like shutdown the system using that sequence.

Comment: Billy ONeal: You should read the post completly before commenting (I have listed 3 ways to do it, not just diabling task manager[which does disable SAS]), and also read the link provided for further information. Mind you this is for WinXP only.

Comment: I've read the whole post, and Billy is still correct. The only solution here that actually disables the secure attention sequence is number 2. And yes, that only works on Windows XP, which is a 10 year old operating system. In related news, there are plenty of ways to get around this in Windows 98, too. Fortunately, people have finally moved on. Task Manager has absolutely nothing to do with the SAS. For embedded systems, there are far better options than any of these.

Comment: Cody Gray: The questions is about Windows XP. No point banging on about how old it is and how it can be done in other OSes.

Comment: It is indeed possible to have the OS not respond to CTRL-ALT-DEL.

Comment: @Jörgen: No, it is not. Setting the `DisableTaskMgr` key or disabling it via group policy does not disable the SAS -- it will stop the task manager from appearing but it will still bring up the list of options e.g. "Log Off", "Lock", etc.

Comment: @Billy, oh, that's strange. I must have dreamt shipping a working product. Hint: GINA.

Comment: @Jörgen: That's still effectively a filter driver. It is not disabling the task manager.

Comment: @Billy, it is disabling all standard processing of SAS. It is making it a no-op. Why debate it? It is irrelevant if the kernel still sees the key combination as SAS, because nothing will happen in user space, given a custom gina.dll. The OP wanted to know if he could turn off the effects of Ctrl+Alt+Del, and he can, if he goes the extra yard. Your oppinion doesn't change fact.

Comment: @Jörgen: I don't understand your hostility here. I'm *agreeing with you* on the GINA front. I'm saying the "Disable task manager" answers are wrong. GINA is a kernel hook though, so you're in effect overriding the Kernel. That was my whole point. I agree with #2 on this answer. #1 and #3 are wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is.

CTRL+ALT+DEL, known as the [Secure Attention Sequence (SAS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_attention_key), can't be intercepted through the common Global Windows Hook mechanism though.

The option you have to intercept SAS that I know of, not mattering the situation, is just one: a driver.

But it doesn't need to be a full blown device driver, it can be a simpler one known as a filter driver. You'll need to learn how to do kernel development which is not so trivial and will require you to do, for example, kernel debugging with two machines. If you expect to use your driver at other machines with newer Windows, you'll need to sign your driver since  Windows Vista x64 and newer will not load non-signed drivers, only the x86 version of these operating systems are allowed to do it. And you'll get the risk of getting some funny BSOD in the way.

The official microsoft sample for a keyboard filter driver is the [kbfiltr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/ff542312) sample.

Now, there's a much simpler way to circumvent all of this: use some library that communicates with a driver to do all this dirty work. And this is what I have tried to do.

I've developed a library, which I call [Interception](http://oblita.com/Interception), that allows one to, well..., *intercept* device input from a common user mode program while using the powers of a device driver. It's a small and simple C api that internally communicates with drivers which I've properly signed.

You must use an [installer](https://github.com/oblitum/Interception/releases/latest) to install the drivers at your system before using the API.

At my web site there's already a sample for SAS interception and you can also check it out [here](https://github.com/oblitum/Interception/blob/master/samples/cadstop/cadstop.cpp), at github. I'll leave it here for reference:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <utils.h>
#include <interception.h>

using namespace std;

namespace scancode {
    enum {
        esc  = 0x01,
        ctrl = 0x1D,
        alt  = 0x38,
        del  = 0x53,
    };
}

InterceptionKeyStroke ctrl_down = {scancode::ctrl, INTERCEPTION_KEY_DOWN                      , 0};
InterceptionKeyStroke alt_down  = {scancode::alt , INTERCEPTION_KEY_DOWN                      , 0};
InterceptionKeyStroke del_down  = {scancode::del , INTERCEPTION_KEY_DOWN | INTERCEPTION_KEY_E0, 0};
InterceptionKeyStroke ctrl_up   = {scancode::ctrl, INTERCEPTION_KEY_UP                        , 0};
InterceptionKeyStroke alt_up    = {scancode::alt , INTERCEPTION_KEY_UP                        , 0};
InterceptionKeyStroke del_up    = {scancode::del , INTERCEPTION_KEY_UP | INTERCEPTION_KEY_E0  , 0};

bool operator==(const InterceptionKeyStroke &first,
                const InterceptionKeyStroke &second) {
    return first.code == second.code && first.state == second.state;
}

bool shall_produce_keystroke(const InterceptionKeyStroke &kstroke) {
    static int ctrl_is_down = 0, alt_is_down = 0, del_is_down = 0;

    if (ctrl_is_down + alt_is_down + del_is_down < 2) {
        if (kstroke == ctrl_down) { ctrl_is_down = 1; }
        if (kstroke == ctrl_up  ) { ctrl_is_down = 0; }
        if (kstroke == alt_down ) { alt_is_down = 1;  }
        if (kstroke == alt_up   ) { alt_is_down = 0;  }
        if (kstroke == del_down ) { del_is_down = 1;  }
        if (kstroke == del_up   ) { del_is_down = 0;  }
        return true;
    }

    if (ctrl_is_down == 0 && (kstroke == ctrl_down || kstroke == ctrl_up)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (alt_is_down == 0 && (kstroke == alt_down || kstroke == alt_up)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (del_is_down == 0 && (kstroke == del_down || kstroke == del_up)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (kstroke == ctrl_up) {
        ctrl_is_down = 0;
    } else if (kstroke == alt_up) {
        alt_is_down = 0;
    } else if (kstroke == del_up) {
        del_is_down = 0;
    }

    return true;
}

int main() {
    InterceptionContext context;
    InterceptionDevice device;
    InterceptionKeyStroke kstroke;

    raise_process_priority();

    context = interception_create_context();

    interception_set_filter(context, interception_is_keyboard,
                            INTERCEPTION_FILTER_KEY_ALL);

    while (interception_receive(context, device = interception_wait(context),
                                (InterceptionStroke *)&kstroke, 1) > 0) {
        if (!shall_produce_keystroke(kstroke)) {
            cout << "ctrl-alt-del pressed" << endl;
            continue;
        }

        interception_send(context, device, (InterceptionStroke *)&kstroke, 1);

        if (kstroke.code == scancode::esc)
            break;
    }

    interception_destroy_context(context);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting hooks into the keyboard system is not going to do the trick, despite what some here are saying.

The keyboard system works by issuing a particular hardware interrupt. The OS traps this interrupt and responds to it appropriately. This would be the thing affected by keyboard hooks.

The sequence CTRL-ALT-DEL issues a separate hardware interrupt from the other keys. This was done originally so that the reboot command would be available even when the other keyboard commands were frozen. (Although a terminate-stay-resident application in MS-DOS could still trap and handle the interrupt.)

The reason the key sequence is used now for log-in is because of this behavior. Since it issues a separate hardware interrupt, the sequence is used to verify that some other application hasn't put its hooks in. This is to prevent spoofing the login prompt.

I am not saying that it is impossible to trap this interrupt and modify its behavior. I don't know that it's not. But it will not be as simple as putting hooks into the keyboard handling code.

Comment: It's definitely not easy but definitely possible. There is even some documentation out there about writing your own msgina.dll. Unless you really need to completely cut off any response to those keys though, you should consider simpler, less-rigurous methods though (@moon).

Answer (score 2):

Winlogon just calls `SetWindowsHookEx` on the default desktop to trap CAD. Since only a thread that called `SetWindowsHookEx` can unregister the hook, it is made sure that no other process can steal it. In addition the keyboard hook only works on the process desktop. You can try to switch to a new desktop and hit CAD. 
Some internal info [you'll find here](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2008/12/23/locking-a-workstation-part-2/).

Comment: Winlogon does not provide the Control Alt Delete hook -- it works even outside of winlogon. The Secure Attention Sequence is provided directly by the Kernel.

Comment: You are wrong for XP. 
Read this article: http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2008/12/23/locking-a-workstation-part-2/
And there is no outside of winlogon. If a user can control a session, then there is winlogon.

Answer (score 1):

Why do all the answers say it isn't possible? It is very much possible, for example here's how to enable it in case a virus has disabled it:

> ```
> Click Start
> Click Run
> Enter gpedit.msc in the Open box and click OK
> In the Group Policy settings window
>
> Select User Configuration
> Select Administrative Templates
> Select System
> Select Ctrl+Alt+Delete options
> Select Enable Task Manager
> ```

How to make this disable it and how to do it from code I'll let you figure out (hint: you'll probably want to edit some [registry keys](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsXP/UserTips/Customization/EnableDisableTaskManagerinWindowsXPHomePro.html)) as this question is pretty fishy.

You can also install various keyboard hooks that alter the functionality of ctrl + alt + delete.

You can read about the registry API [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875%28VS.85%29.aspx).

If you want NOTHING to happen when you press ctrl alt delete, look into windows hooks and windows API hooking. Those are not easy to code; if you want API hooking then I suggest [this](http://www.madshi.net/) library - <strike>you might be able to do this with classic windows hooks however.</strike>
You'll need to write your own msgina.dll to rigurously hook this function. If you don't absolutely have to cut off any response to this command (and you probably don't), then you can most likely get away with simpler methods.

Comment: Maybe semantics but that doesn't disable CTRL+ALT+DEL it just changes what happens when you press it!

Comment: @Martin: yes, semantics. Unless you physically break the keyboard, then you truly can't disable it. Changing what happens when you press it is what the question is **most likely** about.

Comment: No, this does *not* disable Ctrl-Alt-Del; it just changes what is displayed in the dialog which C-A-D pops up.

Comment: That controls the availability of Task Manager. Ctrl + Alt + Delete has nothing to do with the Task Manager in Vista and newer, it is just a command handled by winlogon.exe and displays a menu. The Task Manager is brought up using Ctrl + Shift + Esc.

Comment: Again, it depends on your definition of disable. So, how do you define disable? Make it so the OS doesn't respond to the keypresses? You can use a device driver to hook keypresses, but arguably the device driver is part of the OS, so the OS still responds to the keypresses. EVERYTHING just changes what is displayed, except for hitting the keyboard with a hammer. I am guessing the OP is interested in disabling taskmanager; if not, he'll have to resort to advanced hooks anyway.

Comment: That's why we need the OP to explain his end goal. Why he is trying to do it. e.g. If it is to disable certain options that come up in a domain environment there are supported ways of doing it.

Comment: You can not trap SAS with keyboard hooks.

Answer (score 1):

This is in response to what the OP wants to do, not the question itself...

The easiest way accomplish your goal would be to write a keyboard filter driver, which discards all input. (This is really the only *correct* way of disabling all input I can think of, and is the method used by products such as LogMeIn)

Comment: If someone could comment as to what they think is wrong with this answer it would be much appreciated. Disabling the task manager is not disabling control alt delete. Therefore, to the OP's asked question "can I disable Control Alt Delete" -- the only way to do so is to trap the keypress before it gets into the kernel proper. And the only way to do that is to be a driver -- e.g. sit in between the kernel and the keyboard.