# ctrl+alt+del disable using c in window OS

Tags: c++, c, windows

How to disable <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> using C in Window OS? I tried

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVERRUNNING, true, &bOldState, 0);
```

but it doesn't working for me. Can you kindly guide me, so that I can make it possible.

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432262/i-want-to-disable-ctrlaltdel-in-windows-xp-in-my-ansi-c-code

Comment: What are you trying to do? write a virus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SPI_SETSCREENSAVERRUNNING` parameter you are using is designed for screensavers on Windows 95.  It works on Windows 95/98/ME and earlier.  It does not work on Windows NT/2000/XP/Vista.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> Hotkey combo can be disabled on Windows NT/2000/XP/Vista, but not usually from an application (user mode).  Here are the mechanisms I'm familiar with.

*I haven't tried it on Windows 7, but I'm sure some or all of these techniques still work there.*

1. A GINA DLL can intercept the CAD sequence, but that may be overkill.  It works because Windows registers the CAD Hotkey and sends a callback to GINA DLL to handle the action when you press it.  A replacement GINA DLL can handle the callback differently (ignoring it), but it may be tricky to do this and remain compatible with other login mechanisms using other custom GINA DLLs.
2. You can write a keyboard driver to intercept it.  There is pretty good free source code on the net for it if you search for it.  Look for the Ctrl2Cap driver and similar things.  (This driver remaps the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys to mimic old keyboard layouts.)
3. You may also be able to "remap" keys in the registry to achieve your goal using the Scan Code Mapper.  They added this in Windows 2000.  It's limited, but workable in some situations.  See [this MSDN page](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/archive/w2kscan-map.mspx) for details.  Pay attention to the limitations, though.  For example, it requires a reboot for the change to take effect.
4. Finally, you can disable the Task Manager and other features through an administrative setting using the Windows Admin Toolkit.  It still interrupts everything to show you a "You can't do that" dialog.  But at least it works to limit users' access to the machine.

I wrote a device driver (option 2 on my list above) to block <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> for Windows 95/98 (13 years ago), and later for Windows NT/2000/XP.  I sold a lot of those.  They're still around if you look.

Answer (score 1):

Are you attempting to disable the requirement of <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> for login, or are you trying to disable the hotkey entirely? I don't believe the latter is even possible; it's a built-in OS-level override designed to circumvent any user-level program.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows XP you can write a GINA DLL to do this. Windows 7 doesn't seem to have a GINA DLL anymore though. There may be some sort of policy setting to accomplish the same, but if so I haven't seen it documented.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> is the *Secure Attention Sequence*. The goal is to let the user communicate securely with the OS. It can't be disabled by programs, by design - it would no longer be secure in that case.