# Restrict shortcut keys in IE10 Kiosk mode

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file

I am creating a web page that runs on IE10. I need to create a batch file to launch webstie in kiosk mode. I used the following code in batch file

```
Start "" iexplore.exe -k "file:///C:/MySite/index.html"
```

This opens my page in IE kiosk mode. but my requirement is user only use Alt+F4 to close the site. all other functional keys should be restricted(Such as "Windows+D","Alt+Tab"). Is it possible in batch file? how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

these links have some useful information on the topic.

It looks like a very similar question has already been asked, and the solution involves installing "Auto Hot Key" program then creating a script to remap the hotkeys, and have your 'kiosk' script call it each time it runs.
You may also want to create a second script to 'reverse' the mapping for when needed.

Link: [Disable Ctrl-Alt-Del and shutdown for kiosk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234242/disable-ctrl-alt-del-and-shutdown-for-kiosk)

Link: http://www.autohotkey.com/

Link: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-do-i-change-the-windows-7-keyboard-shortcuts/0110d32d-66c0-4ce7-8682-eeb896e80c3f