# Is it possible to disable Alt for web applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

Is it possible to disable the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key for web applications or is it only possible for windows application using C#. & if it is possible what is the easiest way this can be done.

Comment: And you are trying to do this because...?

Comment: It's a long story.but basically i dont want any student to get out of our locked in browser while he is taking the exam using a combination like Ctrl + Alt + Del to run a taskmgr

Comment: So you really want to ask *this* question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234242/disable-ctrl-alt-del-and-shutdown-for-kiosk

Comment: @m7md sounds like an IT problem, not a web problem.

Comment: I'm confused if it is even possible. cause all links u guys put is talking about issues not necessarily related to  web application

Comment: @m7md, The answer is: It's not possible. Even with `ActiveX` for a web application, you can't prevent Ctrl + Alt + Del combination within a web application.

Answer (score 5):

**It is not possible.** Web applications will run in client's browser. You can't disable `Alt` key on client's machine.

See: [Limitations of Web Applications](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=145&t=Limitations_of_Web_Applications)