# Catch LeaveFullscreen in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, fullscreen

I'm writing an JavaFx-Application and want to force the fullscreen. I tried

```
mainView.getLayout().setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE){
        mainView.getStage().setFullScreen(true);
        }
    });
```

`mainView.getLayout()` returns a StackPane

but that's not a clean solution, when it leaves the fullscreen it automatically switches back to fullscreen. But I want to Catch the LeaveFullScreen and do nothing instead of leave and switch back.

Comment: A key Combination exists to force fullscreen not exist.Write stagename.estExitFullScreenKeyCombination(KeyCombination.none) something like that.Easy to find

Comment: Thanks, i tried "stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);" But the Escape-Key still works, how can i disable it?

Comment: It must be .NONE i think.I am not in computer to check sry.Also set setFullScreenExitMessage () to null .Search this method it bhas a name like this

Comment: stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH); shall do the job. If it is not working, you are not calling it on the correct `Stage`.

Comment: okay, i got it, i have to set setFullscreen(true) after setFullScreenExitKey not before. Thanks Mate!

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to comment this:) From the doc of `setFullScreenExitKeyCombination` : "An internal copy of this value is made when entering FullScreen mode".

Answer (score 1):

The [`fullScreenExitKey` property of the `Stage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#fullScreenExitKeyProperty) can be set to [`KeyCombination.NO_MATCH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.html#NO_MATCH). This prevents any combination of keys from exiting full screen mode.

```
stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
stage.setFullScreen(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `ChangeListener`
 to the `Stage` full screen property:

```
primaryStage.fullScreenProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
                Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
            if(newValue != null && !newValue.booleanValue())
                primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        }
    });
```

For more have a look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282646/how-to-lock-javafx-fullscreen-mode#32284927)