# Why stage.setResizable(false); and stage.setMaximized(true); is not working in JavaFx?

Tags: javafx

I'm using `JavaFx version 8.0.131`
I want to set JavaFx stage maximized but not resizable but following code does not working.

Here is my code:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setMaximized(true);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
}
```

It just does set `Resizable` `false` but not `Maximized` `true`.

Comment: maybe try `stage.setFullSreen(true);`

Comment: Already used but esc does resize at top left corner.

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282646/how-to-lock-javafx-fullscreen-mode) might be able to help you out by creating a listener for when the fullscreen property has changed.

Comment: Thank you I used other code and that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of     `stage.setMaximized(true);`
and `setResizable(false);`
I tried following code that solved the problem.

```
Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    stage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX());
    stage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY());
    stage.setWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());
    stage.setHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());

    stage.show();
```