# How to disable keyboard shortcuts 'Alt + F4' in ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am not able to disable or change the working of these keyboard shortcuts in Electron.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

**Below I have mentioned the 2 different codes for make this change.**

---

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut, path, url} = require('electron')

app.on('ready', () => {
  const ret = globalShortcut.register('alt+f4', function () {
    win.show()
  })
})
```

---

```
{
    role: 'help',
    submenu: [
        {
            label: 'Reload', 
            accelerator: 'Alt + F4',
            click: function (item, focusedWindow) {
                focusedWindow.reload();
            } 
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Ctrl-Alt-Del and shutdown for kiosk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234242/disable-ctrl-alt-del-and-shutdown-for-kiosk)

Comment: Thanks but we have used ElectronJS.

Comment: First set your BrowserWindow option to `closable: false` this should prevent 'Alt+F4'

Comment: Hi Leonardo, thanks for your help but this is not working with my windows app.. below I have mentioned the code: 

**
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1080, height: 720, frame: false, resizable: false, alwaysOnTop:true, closable:false  })**

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it by preventing the `keydown` event on `renderer` process

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    const { key, altKey } = e;
    if (key === 'F4' && altKey) {
        e.preventDefault();   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below code for alt+f4:

```
 window.webContents
 .on("before-input-event",
   (event,input)=>
      { 
        if(input.code=='F4'&&input.alt) 
           event.preventDefault();
      }
  );
```