# Capturing Ctrl+Alt+Del. VMWare does it, but it shouldn't, right?

Tags: vmware

I've been spending my entire computing life (since Windows NT 4.0 at least) on the assumption that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> key combination is held sacred by the operating system - that no program can usurp this key combination and it will always be captured by the kernel's security layer and issue the highest-priority interruption that causes the Security screen to be displayed (except on Windows XP Home Edition when it shell-invoked the Task Manager directly).

However I was using VMWare Player today and I let it capture my mouse and keyboard, but after I was done I wanted to get out and I forgot the hotkey combination (note for future reference, I need to double-tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd> ). I thought I'd <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to invoke the security screen and switch focus to the Task Manager, however when I pressed the keys VMWare Player rebooted my VM - somehow it had captured the keypress.

So this experience taught me that processes can capture CAD, but how did it do it?

#### Update:

- I'm running Windows 7 x64.
- I want to know how VMWare is able to capture CAD keystrokes.

#### Update2:

Having looked at the QA that you linked to, I took a look at my Device Manager and saw that there's the `vmkbd` keyboard class filter that looks like it's VMWares - so it's possible they capture the SAS/CAD keystroke from there.

Comment: What is your host operating system?

Comment: At present your question is vague and nebulous. What exactly are you wanting to know?

Comment: If it works on Windows as the host, they're probably using a driver to achieve it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8748183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, though Chris Morgan (see third comment to my original question) deserves the credit.

> Having looked at the QA that you linked to, I took a look at my Device Manager and saw that there's the vmkbd keyboard class filter that looks like it's VMWares - so it's possible they capture the SAS/CAD keystroke from there.

I did a bit more research (read: I googled for for "vmkbd ctrl alt del") and found other articles and forum threads that corroborate this explanation.

Even so, the idea that a driver can intercept CAD is a bit unnerving, though it makes sense. I do miss the old days before USB when CAD triggered a CPU interrupt in hardware. No drivers required.

Answer (score 0):

This keyboard combination cannot be captured in user mode. It is possible in kernel mode. The (filter) driver is sitting there, in order to capture this *kernel-only* interrupt. Since, it can capture, it can send the same information to user mode process.