# Hook filtering Keyboards HKEYS issue in c

Tags: c++, c, windows

I am filtering the HKEYS by using Hook filtering function, I use the following code to disable Alt+Tab, Alt+Esc, Ctrl+Esc, Windows Key

```
if (((lParam.vkCode == 9)  && (lParam.flags == 32))||
    ((lParam.vkCode == 27) && (lParam.flags == 32))|| 
    ((lParam.vkCode == 27) && (lParam.flags == 0)) ||  
    ((lParam.vkCode == 91) && (lParam.flags == 1)) || 
    ((lParam.vkCode == 92) && (lParam.flags == 1)) || 
    ((true) && (lParam.flags == 32)))

  return 1;
```

Can any one tell me how can I disable Ctrl+Alt+Del? I have tried a lot to filter this but unsuccessful for me.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886076/how-can-i-intercept-all-key-events-including-ctrlaltdel-and-ctrltab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got answer of my own question, ctrl+alt+del can't filter out from hook, the only way to disable ctrl+alt+del is to modify the registry form your code..