# Capturing Ctrl-Alt-Del in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

While just playing with jQuery/JavaScript I ran across this problem. I could capture <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys but NOT <kbd>Del</kbd> and certainly not all of them together.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#target").keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey && event.altKey && event.keyCode == '46') {
            alter("Ctrl-Alt-Del combination");
        }
    });
});
```

Is it possible to capture all these three keys together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure about other operating systems,  but I know that on Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is a system keystroke, which is intercepted at the top level, always by Windows. As far as I know, it is not passed any further on from there, allowing you to KNOW that whatever comes up from it is official.

I know that for Gnome (and I believe KDE), hitting it pulls up the shutdown dialog, and thus, is captured by the window manager, and not passed on.

So, unless Mac just ignores it, no, you cannot get that particular combination, due to its magic to the OS.

EDIT: just something I noticed, you have `alter` not `alert` in your code. I don't think it would work either way with it like that.

Comment: That was a typo. I typed that code. :) - Thank for your response though. Good to know it cannot be done.

Comment: Macs don't really have the `del` key, so it's meaningless for Macs too.

Comment: @shosti: Not true. Macs do have the 'delete=>' key on the full sized keyboards. On the smaller keyboards it can be pressed using fn+backspace (backspace is called 'delete' on some apple keyboard layouts)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible.

You see, all kinds of user input, be it via keyboard or mouse or whatever IO device, is passed to your application through Windows in the form of messages. However, there are some dedicated messages that are captured and handled at the windows OS level. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is one such operation. Windows would not pass on this message any further.

Answer (score 1):

[How can I intercept all key events, including ctrl+alt+del and ctrl+tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886076/how-can-i-intercept-all-key-events-including-ctrlaltdel-and-ctrltab)

... probably not.

Answer (score 1):

After searching, I found this, http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html
It basically said different browser and different OS will get different behavior for the del key. If <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> is used on Windows, the Windows shows Task Manager before detected, which loses focus which C+A+D is not detected.