# Disabling keys in Windows

Tags: javascript

how to disable <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>,<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>,<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, keys using JavaScript for Windows?

Comment: You need to disable your CAPS LOCK buddy.

Comment: This sounds like an attempt by someone trying to hack my computer or simply "lock" my browser to a given page - which causes me to add the site to my hosts file to block it forever.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot disable <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd> that is a windows special key.

You cant disable <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> as those as also special keys.

You should have no reason at all to disable those via Javascript.

Comment: +1 just for using the kbd tags -- nice, did not know that one :)

Comment: @bmoeskau - Yea it really adds a nice touch =)

Comment: i've seen software do it.. so it is possible the main question resides how is this done ?

Comment: @user613326 - sure, software can do it, but he is asking how to do it in javascript

Answer (score 2):

You should not do that is my answer. That would definitely make me not visit that site again. Even if it's an internal site, disabling keys is a bad workaround to whatever problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

[Capturing Ctrl-Alt-Del in JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807838/capturing-ctrl-alt-del-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Any implementation of Javascript that allowed you to do so I would consider buggy, and might even change browsers to avoid. A website should *never* take over my machine like that.

There are almost no good reasons to allow web pages to do that to a user, and a whole host of evil reasons. I'll give you the benifit of the doubt that you aren't trying to do something evil, but I can't imagine what that could be.