# Creating a program that stop the user from accessing the system and prevents CTRl Alt DEL

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a custom login program for my PC, rather than using the usual Windows 7 login(I'll just remove my password and have my account auto login, my program will run after windows startup), and I need to disallow the CTRL Alt Del key combination, and  I want to catch and disable the various methods a user might try to exit the application.

I also need the program to run above all other running program and stop the user from accessing the system and other running application

So, how can I prevent user from accessing the system while my programi is running??
I know I can use a process check to kill taskmgr.exe, but not sure about that menu.
I also assume I can just prevent my program from exiting when Alt+F4 is pressed, by canceling an event, like OnQuit or what ever it is called.

Thank you to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Not possible. If you want to replace the Windows login sequence with a custom version, [you have the ability to do that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsvistasecurity/archive/2006/08/25/724271.aspx). But it's not as simple as hooking the SAS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I intercept all key events, including ctrl+alt+del and ctrl+tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886076/how-can-i-intercept-all-key-events-including-ctrlaltdel-and-ctrltab)

Comment: *If* your purpose is legitimate, do it the right way — http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsvistasecurity/archive/2006/08/25/724271.aspx

Comment: Dmitry Kushnier: I assume questions like this come up a lot? I bet half of them don't have legit reasons, or pretend to(Honestly, I hate viruses, and things that take passwords. I don't see what the purpose of them even are, they annoy me a lot.)

Comment: "Honestly, I hate viruses, and things that take passwords." Everyone hates those...their purpose is to steal your info...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CTRL-ALT-DELETE is, by design in Windows 7, a secure, system-only key combo... so that the user KNOWS they are using a system screen, and not some sort of lock screen lookalike app designed to hijack their password.

Comment: So I assume its completely prevented? I assume it shouldn't matter too much, as no-one under the age of 12 will be using it(besides me of course), and these people aren't exactly computer skilled :)

Comment: Yes, Windows prevents you from doing this. It's a security feature that's been built in since the early days. There have been various holes in the security layer, but they've been quite well patched by now. Security is a big deal, and it doesn't have anything to do with the age of the users. You want to make sure that you're only giving your password to Windows. Pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del (the secure attention sequence, or SAS) is the way that the user knows they're doing that. Otherwise, someone could write malware that masquerades as Windows and steals passwords, a huge problem on corporate nets.

Comment: Yea, I can see that being a big problem, but I noticed schools usually have a custom login system or some sort, I assume they probably replaced the actual windows login system.

Comment: @CokaCola: No, I've never seen a school with a custom login system, at least not as the question describes. What you're probably thinking of is a login prompt provided by networking software like Novell Netware, but this doesn't replace the secure attention sequence. Netware actually replaces `msgina.dll` with its own custom version, which was the official way to do these things in XP and earlier versions. That's no longer the case as of Vista, but there are alternatives. Investigate the links posted in comments to the original question for details. But I'm betting it's way overkill for you.

Answer (score 1):

To display your window above all others, set the `Window.Topmost` (WPF) or `Form.TomMost` (Windows Forms) property to `true`

I have no idea how to suppress the system screen. I'm afraid Steve is right about it. Not even virtualization software like VMware is not able to do this.

Comment: Yea, I know how to keep it above all windows using that method, and along with the full-screen property, it is usually helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned elsewhere Ctrl-Alt-Delete is buried deep down in the OS and not ment to be tampered with.

Depending on which effect you want to obtain by hooking up the key press and your rights on the system you could consider revoking access to system shutdown using the windows access control system. I found a blog about it using Windows XP here: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-xp/xp-prevent-shutdown/

While there might be differences on Windows 7, you still have the `gpedit.msc` management plugin available and there is a policy named `Shut down the system` that by default is available to administrators, users and backup operators. I would look at the revoking access to users as a means to solve whatever-you-want-to-obtain.

Comment: Since the other people who will try to use it won't know much about this sort of thing, I won't bother preventing the system screen, just probably killing the Task Manager, to prevent the process of my program being exited.