# Catch a hardware interrupt

Tags: visual-studio-2012, device-driver, wdm

I am writing a device driver (kernel level). I am new to kernel space and would like some help in understanding hardware interrupts.

I am writing driver for a new hardware for windows 7

I have already written the Interrupt service routine for all software interrupts.

My question is how do i proceed with writing Interrupt handler which would catch hardware interrupt.

Continuous polling is a bad idea 
so could any one suggest me some other idea to proceed with

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which [O/S and Driver Kit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Driver_Kit) are you using? Which hardware interrupt do you want to catch?

Comment: i am using windows 7
and WDK 7600.16385.1

my device generates a hardware interrupt when my parity bit is set
(as mentioned in datasheet)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should read the documentation and some sample code for how to [Register an ISR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560865(v=vs.85).aspx).

See also [Getting Started on Driver Development](https://stackoverflow.com/q/876155/49942).

Comment: I have read and already created the interrupt handler but 

I am unable to catch hardware interrupt.

According to datasheet of device if received data has parity bit as 1, an hardware interrupt is issued

Comment: There's not enough information to guess what's wrong. Perhaps it's one of: a) device isn't configured to generate interrupt b) device isn't generating interrupt for some other reason c) ISR isn't properly registered d) ?

Comment: All other interrupts are serviced properly just this 1 hardware interrupt is not working.
i think there might be some problem in hardware